# How to do Binding ListBox item on runtime?

Tags: silverlight

I want to do binding to the items that i get from some web service.

I calling the web service method - and i get back some list of strings. 
I want to do on runtime the binding of those item that i got with the list box.

How can i do it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not entirely sure I understand your question, bit if you've got an IEnumerable All you have to do is set the ItemsSource:

```
List<String> strList = new List<string>();
strList.Add("123");
strList.Add("456");
ListBox1.ItemsSource = str;
```

Comment: I did not mean to add strings as you wrote. But i found how to do it. Thanks.